How to block user sign-up when using signInWithPopup when exception is thrown in Firebase Authentication?
I’m using Firebase Authentication with Google Sign-In in my web app. I have a custom signUpWithGoogle method to handle user registration in my custom Backend. However, when calling signInWithPopup, it automatically creates and signs in the user if their account doesn't exist. Is there a way I can block the user from auto sign in as signUpWithGoogle indeed throws an error (e.g. The invitation link is invalid). I use this in my custom register form for when people are invited to my web app, they can use traditional email and pass which works perfectly with my backend, but google sign up doesn't work as perfectly, because the invitation link may be invalid and signUpWithGoogle returns an error, but he still gets signed up and is signed in
Here’s the code:
const authenticateWithGoogle = async (invitationToken?: string) => {
    try {
        const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider());
        const additionalUserInfo = getAdditionalUserInfo(result);
        const isFirstTime = additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser;
        if (isFirstTime) {
            // Handle first-time registration
            const user = result.user;
            const token = await user.getIdToken();
            await signUpWithGoogle({ token, invitationToken }).unwrap();
            await router.push('/dashboard/onboarding');
        } else {
            await router.push('/dashboard');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during Google authentication:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

